# Как получить завтрашнюю дату в таком формате: 2020-11-04T00:00:00

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

Я получил завтрашнюю дату вот так:

```
const d = new Date();
const tomorrow = d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);

console.log(d)
```

Консоль показывает:

```
Wed, 04 Nov 2020 20:00:09 GMT
```

Как мне получить дату в формате

```
2020-11-04T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать `console.log(d.toISOString)`, то будет в нужном формате. [Вот документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) по toISOString.